# Coordinatization Theorem Exemple

Tags: nonassociative-algebras, jordan-algebras

I am studying Coordinatization Theorems, in Jacobson's book. But it is so hard to understand, I would like an easy exemple of direct application of the Coordinatization Theorem, with an easy algebra, it can be the algebra $M_n(K)^+$ of $n \times n$ matrices.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you cite the theorem? And maybe also include the things you do understand.